# SSH Connection to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh

I have hit an issue and I am unsure as to where it is going wrong. I am establishing an SSH connection to my remote server and from there I am trying to access a MySQL Database. The SSH connection connects properly however, when attempting to access the MySQL db I keep getting an error.

**I have searched beyond belief for almost a week before running for help**

**UPDATE!!!**

Alright so I have been able to pull this down to being something to do with JSCH. I established an SSH connection using putty externally and ran the code without actually using JSCH to make the SSH connection and I was able to access teh DB entirely. At this point any help with **JSCH** would be very helpful.

```
    int lport=3306;
    String rhost="SERVERNAME";
    String host="SERVERNAME";
    int rport=3306;
    String user="USERNAME";
    String password="SSHPass";
    String dbuserName = "DBUSER";
    String dbpassword = "DBPWD";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    String driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session= null;
    try{
        //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
        System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

        //mysql database connectivity
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbuserName, dbpassword);
        System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            conn.close();
        }
        if(session !=null && session.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException
MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Data.SQLConnection.getConnection(SQLConnection.java:49)
    at finalproject.Dashboard.jButton1ActionPerformed(Dashboard.java:391)
    at finalproject.Dashboard.access$200(Dashboard.java:37)
    at finalproject.Dashboard$4.actionPerformed(Dashboard.java:221)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try connecting to the server on the command line - it may be a firewall issue

Comment: Using both CMD and Putty allows me to connect, from there I can pull up the DB in MySql Workbench with no problems :( The logs server side also show the SSH connection.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, so I'm not sure what your particular problem is, but I recently wrote a [comprehensive tutorial on securing MySQL via SSL](https://www.edcottrell.com/2015/04/26/using-ssl-mysql/). You may find it helpful.

Comment: Is session.setPortForwardingL a blocking call? Could it be that the mysql connection is initiated before the port is fully forwarded?

Comment: @Erik Man So to test this I established the SSH connection outside of the program to try to see if I could just establish a connection and I received the same error. For some reason it isn't getting live with the SQL db.

Comment: Just in case ... Have you tried with `String rhost="127.0.0.1";
String host="127.0.0.1";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname";`?

Comment: @Fox unfortunately I have and I receive the same error. The only way I have been able to get it to work is to bypass JSCH and use Putty or CMD to make an external SSH connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOOOOO I got it working! So what I did (and I have no idea why this works) is I just created a new Class that establishes the SSH connection with JSCH. I then put all the fun SQL stuff in another. From my dashboard gui under the connect event handler I added the JSCH connection first and after that I connect to the SQL DB. 
Thank you everyone for all of your help! You are all awesome!